# Action Script 3 error 1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var playScreen:AvoiderGame;

        public function DocumentClass() 
        {
            playScreen = new AvoiderGame();
            addChild( playScreen );
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at AvoiderGame()
    at DocumentClass()
```

Comment: `AvoiderGame()` code demanded.

Comment: No need for code very likely, it's probably another of the billion times somebody tries to use 'stage' inside a constructor.